# Inner Exception Error: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, insert, foreign-keys, constraints, inner-exception

I am trying to add the Id of the Ticket Table to another table (TrackTicket) and insert it to the field (TicketId) and I got this error

Error: An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

-- The Inner Exception Error:The insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint\"FK_dbo.TrackTickets_dbo.Tickets_TicketId\". The conflict occured in database \ "databasename" \", table\"dbo.Tickets"\, column 'Id'.\the statement has been terminated

What does it mean? Help!

Code

Controller

```
_context.Tickets.Add(new Ticket {ClientId = userId , Subject = viewModel.Ticket.Subject, TypeOfTicket = viewModel.Ticket.TypeOfTicket, ConcernedDept = viewModel.Ticket.ConcernedDept, Date = DateTime.Now});

_context.TicketContents.Add(new TicketContent {Subject = viewModel.Ticket.Subject, Content = viewModel.TicketContent.Content});

_context.TrackTickets.Add(new TrackTicket { ClientId = userId,TicketId = viewModel.Ticket.Id  ,StatusHelpDesk = "Received", DateHelpDeskReceived = DateTime.Now });

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know you scheme fully, but you are creating or inserting a new ticket, and also creating or inserting a track ticket with a reference to ticket while you did not set or retrieve the id of the ticket.

This line has no id yet. Either set the id here, or create a variable ticket and use that id to link is to the TrackTickets.
    _context.Tickets.Add(new Ticket {ClientId = userId, Subject = viewModel.Ticket.Subject, TypeOfTicket = viewModel.Ticket.TypeOfTicket, ConcernedDept = viewModel.Ticket.ConcernedDept, Date = DateTime.Now});

The add will fail as TicketId can not be linked to something (no ticket with that Id has been inserted.

```
_context.TrackTickets.Add(new TrackTicket { ClientId = userId, TicketId = viewModel.Ticket.Id, StatusHelpDesk = "Received", DateHelpDeskReceived = DateTime.Now });
```

The way you can use this, if you autogenerate the ticketId is following:

```
var newTicket = new Ticket {ClientId = userId, Subject = viewModel.Ticket.Subject, TypeOfTicket = viewModel.Ticket.TypeOfTicket, ConcernedDept = viewModel.Ticket.ConcernedDept, Date = DateTime.Now}  
_context.Tickets.Add(newTicket);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

If you now reuse the newTicket object, this will have an id. So in the add for trackTickets, use the id of the newTicket

```
_context.TrackTickets.Add(new TrackTicket { ClientId = userId, TicketId = newTicket.Id, StatusHelpDesk = "Received", DateHelpDeskReceived = DateTime.Now });
```

---

If you don't autogenerate your ticket id, you have to set the id in the creation of the ticket (the add to context):

```
var newTicket = new Ticket { Id = viewModel.Ticket.Id, ClientId = userId, Subject = viewModel.Ticket.Subject, TypeOfTicket = viewModel.Ticket.TypeOfTicket, ConcernedDept = viewModel.Ticket.ConcernedDept, Date = DateTime.Now}
```

Comment: Where do i created the variable for the ticket to get the id? and it needs to go to the _context.SaveChanges() to created the Ticket Id right?